# History stack class with (preferably) hidden history and optional max size

Tags: javascript

all.

I want to create an object type (class?) that stores a history stack. This works:

```
function Stack(_max = Infinity) {
    const stack = [], maxSize = _max;
    var count = 0;
    return {
        log: function(x){
            if(stack.size > maxSize) { stack.pop(); }
            stack.unshift({
                n: (() => count++)(),
                a: x
            });
        },
        unlog: function() { stack.shift(); },
        show: function() { return stack; },
        last: function() { return stack[0]; }
    }
}
```

It does have a bit of a "bug": when I run the `log` method, the counter starts at 0 (I'd like it to start at 1, but that's not really important). This hides the stack but doesn't respect the size-limit of it (if I log more than 3 times on `hist = [new] Stack(3)`, the size of the stack increases (the `[ ]` in the code are meant to say that the `new` keyword is optional in the declaration; neither with nor without it does the stack size remain fixed). So I tried this:

```
class Pile {
    #maxSize;
    #stack;
    construtor(_max = Infinity) { this.#maxSize = _max; this.#stack = []; }
    log(x) { if(this.#stack.size > this.#max) { this.#stack.pop(); } this.#stack.unshift(x);  }
    unlog(x) { this.#stack.shift(); }
    show() { return this.#stack; }
    last() { return this.#stack[0]; }
}
```

when I declare `pile = new Pile(3)` and then run `pile.log(0)` I get the error `Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`. I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong in both approaches. Concretely:

1. how do I pass the argument `_max` to the final object so that it keeps the stack size bounded?;
2. why is `this.#stack` undefined in the class declaration?

(Also, help on getting the counter to start at 1 would be lovely.)

Thanks!

Comment: it's `stack.length` not `stack.size`

Answer (score 0):

For the second class, `Pile`, it is possible to use the hash symbol to hide variables. This works (except on Firefox ESR, as far as I can tell):

```
class Pile {
    #maxSize;
    #stack;
    constructor(_max = Infinity) {this.#maxSize = _max; this.#stack = [];}
    log(x) {
        if(this.#stack.length >= this.#maxSize) { this.#stack.pop(); } 
        this.#stack.unshift(x);
    }
    unlog(x) { this.#stack.shift(); }
    show() { return this.#stack; }
    last() { return this.#stack[0]; }
}

let pile = new Pile(2);
pile.log('a');
pile.log('b');
pile.show(); // ["b", "a"]
pile.log('c');
pile.show();// ["c", "b"]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is not such property as `size` in an array, it's `length`.

You cant use `#` as variable name.

In your class you misspelled `constructor` (missing `c`) and there no such variable as `max`

```js
function Stack(_max = Infinity) {
    const stack = [], maxSize = _max;
    var count = 1;
    return {
        log: function(x){
            if(stack.length >= maxSize) { stack.pop();}
            stack.unshift({
                n: (() => count++)(),
                a: x
            });
        },
        unlog: function() { stack.shift(); },
        show: function() { return stack; },
        last: function() { return stack[0]; }
    }
}


class Pile {
    constructor(_max = Infinity) {this.maxSize = _max; this.stack = [];}
    log(x) {if(this.stack.length >= this.maxSize) { this.stack.pop(); } this.stack.unshift(x);  }
    unlog(x) { this.stack.shift(); }
    show() { return this.stack; }
    last() { return this.stack[0]; }
}

const s = new Stack(3);
s.log("stack1");
s.log("stack2");
s.log("stack3");
s.log("stack4");
s.log("stack5");
console.log(s.show());


const p = new Pile(3);
p.log("pile1");
p.log("pile2");
p.log("pile3");
p.log("pile4");
p.log("pile5");
console.log(p.show());
```